# Animation not working in scene and game but works in asset bundle

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, animator, mixamo

[The animation works in the asset bundle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88AOe.png)
[It won't work on my game object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJSFT.png)

I tried open ai and videos and youtube and unity forums and stackoverflow and they don't give me a single answer. I want the animation to work on the gameobj.

Comment: theres a lot to animations.. are you sure the animation is compatible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you problem is that your gameObject "cube" inside "lao8" does not have an armature. The animation is looking for children ordered under the "cube" gameObject to move the character like its intended.

However there are no such children under the "cube" gameObject. You would have to go to the software you used to create the "cube" mesh and add an armature and bones to it. Then you have to export it and make sure to assign the new bones to the avatar "Lao8".

This is very simplified and Im sorry I cant help you more. Maybe look into some tutorials on character rigging / character animation and how to export it to unity. Good luck! :)

Comment: I fixed it already tk